# What does double brackets mean in this condition?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, brackets

This below is my for-loop and im a beginner so i need help to understand what [i] means where it says ".checked" and ".value".  Also, does "var i" stand for "variable i"? Side note: this loop is for a list of checkboxes.

```
for (var i=0; i<flightprices.length; i++) {

if (flightprices.length[i].checked) {

flightPrice = +flightprices[i].value;
}}
```

Comment: Does you code even execute?

Comment: that code `flightprices.length[i]`  is just wrong. It should be `flightprices[i].checked`

Comment: Yes my code does execute, i just need to understand what im doing

Comment: How'd you write the code if you don't know what it does?

Comment: Tutorials.. I would appreciate if i just could get some answes to my questions haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this code results in an error, I can tell you the following.

- `var i=0;` is defining a variable named `i` to the value `0`.
- `flightprices[i]` means the `i+1`th element of the array `flightprices`. `[]` notation is an array selector. Because JavaScript is 0-indexed, `flightprices[0]` means the first element, `flightprices[1]` is the second element, and so on.

### Why there is an error

This line:

```
if (flightprices.length[i].checked) {
```

tries to find element `i` of `flightprices.length`, however the length of something is always an integer, and integers aren't arrays.

Comment: So in this case, "[i]" or "i+1th" basically means the checked element that the variable "i" selected in the loop?

Comment: @Sjan Correct, the `if` is checking every value in `flightprices` to see if they are checked or not.

Comment: Thank you so much!